# Cannot connect using smartbro in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wubi, internet

I have just installed ubuntu 12.10 and in order to access the internet, I used my Smart Bro - Model MF180(Plug and Play USB Stick) but I can't connect to the internet. Are there some modifications or commands that I have to do to enable it?

Comment: Have you checked this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2001525

Comment: oh, I have checked that one already but I don't know how does that "get the python script...and run.." so I can't really follow

Comment: Your MF180 connects via USB? Run `lsusb` and give us the output so that we know the vendor ID and product ID of your Smart Bro, it works wonders when googleing for configuring USB peripherals in Linux. Also, did you install Ubuntu via Wubi? Do you have access to a computer where Ubuntu was installed directly to the hard disk without Wubi?

Comment: Here are the results from lsusb:
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub,
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub,
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub,
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub,
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Comment: Sorry for the messy format. And yes, I installed ubuntu via wubi. No, I don't have access to a computer with those characteristics. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

first thing you should do is to plug in your usb modem. next is click the icon on the upper right corner of your unity desktop. the one thats beside the rythmbox player. click edit connections. click the mobile broadband tab. click add then follow the instructions.after setting that up, close the network connections window. wait for a few seconds then click again the icon beside the rythmbox player. you should be able to click smart bro to connect to internet. a more detailed instructions can be found here http://ramfree17.net/capsule/2011/11/using-smart-bro-plug-it-in-linux/

Comment: yeah. solved it for quite some time now. but either way, thanks :)